# Expect - parse all occurrences of a pattern and store in a variable

Tags: expect, tcl

I am trying to process multiple mac addresses from output of a program. Output is in below format -

```
Device B0:CA:68:CF:88:54 dev1
Device DC:16:B2:AE:FB:8F dev2
Device B0:CA:68:CF:88:11 dev3
Device DC:16:B2:AE:FB:22 dev4
```

I want to store mac addresses along with their names in a file
And I want to store mac addresses in a variable and process further.

I am struggling with it in Expect. How to do it ? Please help

**Below command works but only gives single Mac -**

```
expect -re "Device.*(\[0-9A-Z]\[0-9A-Z]:\[0-9A-Z]\[0-9A-Z]:\[0-9A-Z]\[0-9A-Z]:\[0-9A-Z]\[0-9A-Z]:\[0-9A-Z]\[0-9A-Z]:\[0-9A-Z]\[0-9A-Z])"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to interact with this program, you can `exec` it and capture the output easily:

```
set output [exec some_program]

set macs [lmap line [split $output \n] {lindex [split $line] 1}]
```

Ref: [exec](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm), [lmap](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lmap.htm)

If the program needs interaction, it's a little trickier to capture the output. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks. It worked.